# Cumsum along one dimension in an array

Tags: r

say I have an array

```
a <- array(dim=c(2,5), dimnames=list(c(1,2),c(1:5)))
a[] <- 10

   1  2  3  4  5
1 10 10 10 10 10
2 10 10 10 10 10
```

and would like to create something like a cumsum() along one dimension, to get:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
1 10 20 30 40 50
2 10 20 30 40 50
```

Or a declining balance (cumulative remaining):

```
   1  2  3  4  5
1 50 40 30 20 10
2 50 40 30 20 10
```

What is the right way to do this in R (vectorized)?

Not nice, but illustrative:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
 for (j in 1:5) {
  b[i,j] <- sum(a[i,1:j])
 }
}

   1  2  3  4  5
1 10 20 30 40 50
2 10 20 30 40 50
```

declining balance sample (to show why "cumsum()" isn't the answer expected):

```
for (i in 1:2) {
 for (j in 1:5) {
  b[i,j] <- sum(a[i,j:5])
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
apply(a,2,cumsum)
```

for column sums or

```
t(apply(a,1,cumsum))
```

for the rows. You need the `t()` because the shape is otherwise the wrong way round.

Comment: cumsum() won't work for the declining balance (see 2nd example)

Comment: sorry, did not see that. Can you not reverse indices, e.g. t(apply(a[,5:1],1,chums))[,5:1]. A bit messy but might work?

Comment: or  also `t(apply(a, 1, function(x) rev(cumsum(x))))`

Comment: yes, that's neater if you like the anonymous functions. Better than my suggestion

Comment: OK that wokrs, but I'm still hoping for an array-only solution, as the real problem is not a matrix but has more dimensions, thus solution should be vectorized and not looped (*apply).

Comment: there is the matrixStats package that has row and column wise cumulative sum functions.. but only in two dimensions (I think)

Comment: apply should also work for higher dimensions. Try first with sum(), you then just list the ones you want to sum out. With cumsum() it simply turns a vector in place of a single value. Multiple indices even work on 2D objects: apply(a,1:2,print) prints out each element individually.

Answer (score 0):

For cumsum():

```
b<-t(apply(a,1,cumsum))
```

For order:

```
t(apply(b,1,function(x)sort(x, decreasing=T)))
```

Comment: That could work, but would still involve a loop for each dimension (I only show two here, whereas it's more in reality). I am looking for an array operation vectorizable without explicit loops / applys.